# Parsing value with try? and guard returning different values

Tags: swift

**Language Used**: Swift 3

**Xcode Version**: 8.3.2 (8E2002)

I have an extension on `Data` which parses the data into a `JSONObject` of type `Any`

```
extension Data {
    func toJsonObject() -> Any? {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self, options: [])
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now the weird thing is when I use guard the result object seems to be different when using `toJsonObject()` and `try?`

For example

```
guard let dictionary = data.toJsonObject() as? [String: Any] else {
    return
}
```

> `dictionary` is now of type `[String: Any]`

Whereas when I use this:

```
guard let dictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
    return
}
```

> `dictionary` is now of type `[String: Any]?`

Isn't the result of the second code block supposed to be `[String: Any]` instead of the optional `[String: Any]?`

Is this a mistake on Swift or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It will be when you use the extension to get jsonDictionary from data then dictionary will return with the nonoptional value. Because the extension has exception handler. But when you try to get jsonDictionary directly then its provide optional value. Because you use optional `try?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of Swift, I'd say. The use of `try?` means that this becomes a double optional, it's trying to decode straight to that casting of `as? [String: Any]`. Plug this in and check the type on this to see the double optional in action:

```
// Becomes a type of `[String : Any]??`
let dictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(), options: []) as? [String: Any]
```

I think the answer you want is to just add some parentheses to clarify your intent:

```
guard let dictionary = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(), options: [])) as? [String: Any] else {
    return
}
```

Comment: Oooooh, I didn't even consider trying  the `let dictionary = .......` to see which type it was.